# Are there any way to open a form in a div?

Tags: php, forms, moodle, ajaxform

I have this:

My web has 4 divs, the first one container and inside it 3 divs:

- nav
- content
- footer

I mix this web with moodle, when I put the correct login and password, it says me hello and my name in the nav, but when I put the wrong login or password, it redirects me to a new page.

I need that,when I put the wrong login or password, load this page inside the content's div.

Have I to use AjaxForm? How? Are there any more way to do this?

I have this code to the form:

```
<?php
if(empty($USER->id))
{
?><div id="login">
                                <form method="post" action="<?php echo $CFG->httpswwwroot;?>/login/index2.php">
                                        <fieldset>
                                        <label for="username">Usuario:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="usuario">
                                        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                                        <br>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
                                        </fieldset>
                                </form></div>
<a id="boton4">Olvido</a>
<?php
}
else
{
echo 'Hola '.$USER->firstname.'(<a href="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/login/logout.php">Salir</a>)';
}
?>
```

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It would be better perhaps to have a login page that is separate.  You can then use header("location: mylogin.php"); to redirect if a non logged-in user tries to access your page.